# USB Flash Drive does not work on startup

Tags: windows-7, usb, usb-flash-drive

I have a brand new Corsair LS 128GB usb drive. If I keep it plugged into the computer and turn the computer on, it never shows up under Computer. I heard the audible tone to say a USB drive has been recognised and then I get a notification from Windows saying USB drive is not recognised.

If I unplug the flash drive and reinsert it, everything works fine. Why isn't it being recognised and working if I start the computer with the drive already in? All my other USB drives work fine when I do that.

Answer (score -1):

Open Disk Management (Start > Control Panel > System > Administrative Tools > Computer Management > Storage Disk Management).  You should see it listed as "Removable".

- If it says "Not initialized", initialize it.
- If it says "Unallocated", partition it.
- If it doesn't have a drive letter, assign it one.
- If the file system is RAW or unrecognized, format it.